# How to link datasets in jasper report without using tables or subreports

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports, dataset

I have two SQL tables.Data is in one table and the columns for the report is in another table.Therefore I want to use multiple queries in my report and I am doing this by creating a new dataset.Now  I wanted to pass the result of my main query to the query in the dataset.Is there any method to link these?Logically there is no relation between my two tables because one table is a common table for storing values of my entire project.Please help...My project is delayed with this problem.

Comment: You can  use subreports or subdatasets

Comment: Subreports are confusing for my table..May I know how to pass parameters between datasets(Without using tables and lists)

Comment: Without elements it is impossible - you need container to run/use it. Looks like you should use subreport, you can mask/hide it. Another options: is to pass data as parameter (first query is running from code) or changing the query (subquery using)

Comment: Ya...But how to pass data as parameter?But even if i do that will I be able to insert fields from second query(fields in 2nd dataset) to main report?

Comment: I mean some kind of filters. For example: at first step you get some name with help of query, at the second - you are using this value (field name) at filter of second query. Something like this :)

Comment: Let me check that...Thank you:)